# iOS: The specified item could not be found in the keychain and status -25300

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I'm trying to save data in the keychain, but when I retrieve the key I got the following error **The specified item could not be found in the keychain.**

here's the code to do so

```
    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
        guard let key = SecKeyCreateWithData(privateKeyData as CFData,
                                             [  kSecClass as String: kSecClassKey,
                                                kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom,
                                                kSecAttrKeyClass: kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate,
                                                kSecAttrApplicationTag: tag,
                                                kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: 256
                                             ] as CFDictionary,
                                             &error) else {
            if let createKeyError = error {
                print("Failed to create key: \(createKeyError)")
            }
            fatalError("Failed to create key")
        }

    print("Key is created successfully...")

    let query: [String: Any] = [
            kSecClass as String: kSecClassKey,
            kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: tag,
            kSecReturnData as String: true
        ]
        
        var item: CFTypeRef?
        let status = SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, &item)
        let errorDescription = SecCopyErrorMessageString(status,nil)
       print("error = \(errorDescription)")
```

Comment: `SecKeyCreateWithData` does not store the key in the keychain.

Comment: Thanks for your reply it helped a lot I needed to then add this key to keychain, and everything works fine, here's the reference for the solution 

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cryptokit/storing_cryptokit_keys_in_the_keychain

Comment: You can make the `SecKeyCreateWithData` function make it store the key by setting the `kSecAttrIsPermanent` attribute